# How does the PCFMessageAgent handle disconnecting?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

I'm trying to get an understanding of how the [PCFMessageAgent](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/pcf/PCFMessageAgent.html) manages connections to ensure I'm cleaning up everything properly.

For example, at what point is the connection disconnected once I've created the object and I'm done with it?

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent ("localhost", 1414, "CLIENT");
```

The example in the documentation does not show any disconnect call, but I want to be sure I'm not assuming anything.

If it matters, I'm currently on MQ version 7.5, but it doesn't appear this has changed much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always cleanup your stuff.

- If you connect it, then make sure you disconnect from it
- If you open it, then make sure you close it

i.e.

```
if (agent != null)
   agent.disconnect();
```